# How to make a delete button in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, chat, react-fullstack

I am trying to add a delete button in the array of Chats. So when the button is clicked it deletes the particular Chat. But as soon as the component loads all the Chats get deleted because the Chats are in a map function.
**Can anyone help me solve this?**

```
import React,{useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import Chat from './Chat';
import {axiosInstance} from '../axios';
import { IconButton} from '@material-ui/core';
import HighlightOffIcon from '@material-ui/icons/HighlightOff';
function Chats(props) {

    const [matches,setMatches] = useState([]);
    const [Id, setId] = useState('');  

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('Id : ',props.id);
        setId(props.id);
        async function fetchMatches(Id){
            console.log('FETCH MATCHES');
            axiosInstance.get(`/matchlist/${Id}`)
            .then((req) =>{
                setMatches(req.data[0].matches)
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log(err));
        }
        fetchMatches(props.id);
    }, []);


    const removeMatches = (userId,matchId) =>{
           console.log(userId,'  ',matchId);
             axiosInstance.delete(`/matchlist/${userId}/${matchId}`)
             .then((matches) => console.log('matches',matches.data))
             .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }

    return (
        <div className='chats'>
            {
                matches.map((match) =>{
                    return  <div className='chat'>
                                <Chat 
                                    name={match.firstname +' '+match.lastname}
                                    message='message'
                                    timestamp="time taken"
                                    profilePic = {match.imgUrl}
                                    id={match._id}
                                />
                                <IconButton>
                                    <HighlightOffIcon  onClick={removeMatches(Id,match._id)}/>
                                </IconButton>
                            </div>
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Chats;
```

Comment: Might be in how you're returning your element!!!

Comment: You calling the `removeMatches` function on render, try with `onClick={() => removeMatches(Id,match._id)}`

Comment: I think you are not sending user id correctly, you can try to replace ${userId} with props.id directly instead of using state and also you are not updating Id state anyways.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `onClick` event wrongly.

```
 <IconButton>
      <HighlightOffIcon onClick={removeMatches(Id,match._id)}/>
 </IconButton>
```

The correct way:

```
 <IconButton>
      <HighlightOffIcon onClick={() => removeMatches(Id,match._id)}/>
 </IconButton>
```

You want your`removeMatches` function to be called at a later point in time.
In your case as soon as the component renders the `removeMatches` function gets called without even waiting for the click event.

Passing a callback function to the `onClick` ensures that when the click occurs only then run `removeMatches` function and then clear respective items according to your logic.